# Crash when building with Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-7

I ran Visual Studio 2005 on Windows Vista (32-bit). I recently upgraded to Windows 7, and Visual C++ began crashing when building release executables. The actual crash is in mt.exe. I get the message, "mt.exe has stopped working".

Is there a way to solve the crash, or do I need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

`mt.exe` is part of Windows SDK. Maybe you can try the version in Windows 7 SDK.

Comment: I tried installing the Windows SDK, but it failed. I'll try to do a custom install of Windows 7 instead of an upgrade and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean install of Windows 7 (64-bit) instead of an upgrade, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your .NET installation before reinstalling windows. Read this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx